# cv2.namedWindow and imshow is not working properly

Tags: python, opencv, opencv-contrib

This simple piece of code is not working.

```
output = cv2.namedWindow("Output", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow(output, saliencyMap)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

It should show the `saliencyMap` inside `"Output"` window but it is generating two windows(below).

I am using spyder editor and also getting this message.

```
You might be loading two sets of Qt binaries into the same process. Check that all plugins are compiled against the right Qt binaries. Export DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 and check that only one set of binaries are being loaded.
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x7fbf1e53c600) is not the object's thread (0x7fbf1e6f0850).
Cannot move to target thread (0x7fbf1e53c600)`
```

[image]

Comment: Try removing the namedWindow line and just use `cv2.imshow("output", saliencyMap); cv2.waitKey(0)`

Comment: @RahulKedia The image is too big so to fit and view it within the screen, I need to use that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[namedWindow](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow) is a function and it is void function so it gives nothing as output value. [imshow](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#imshow) takes string and Mat as input.

Correct one should be:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img.png')
cv2.namedWindow("Output", cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow("Output", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Thanks! It does the job of merging both instances. 
`cv.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE` didn't shrink image within the screen window. Used `cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL` and it's working now.